# How to group the rows and move them into new column in the same table?

Tags: sql-server

I want to group the rows and move them into new column in the same table. Here is my ilustration:
[image: table ilustration]

and this is the query that I've made so far:

```
SELECT 
    month([date]) as bulan, 
    [type] as tipe,
    SUM([net qty]) total_karton, 
    CAST(SUM([cm1 (rp)]) as decimal) as total_uang
FROM 
    tbl_weeklyflash_ID
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(month,[date],CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) between 0 and 2
GROUP BY 
    month([date]),
    [type]
ORDER BY 
    month([date]), [type]
```

how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You want a `PIVOT` - there's a good example at http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1019/crosstab-queries-using-pivot-in-sql-server-2005/